# tire working with several elastic instances.. how?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm digging into Tire gem documentation. I need some way to search against another elastic instance or create index on another elastic instance.
Don't ask me why - it's architecture problem.

We can define some basic settings within block:

```
Tire.configure do
  url 'http://localhost:9200/'
end
```

What should I do to run some command against another instance
The first idea is create subclass and redefine url, but it's sounds bad for me.
Does anybody know clean way to do thats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tire does not allow to connect to another cluster in the same Ruby process. That is a sad consequence of the design and will be fixed in future versions of the client.

Your options here, depending on what capabilities you need, are:

1/ Use a different process for connecting to the other cluster, use something like Redis to implement publish/subscribe communication between the processes.

2/ Use a different Ruby client.

3/ Use `Tire::Configuration.client` with a different URL.

Comment: Please clarify the 3rd option. use Tire::Configuration.client in what way?

Comment: karmi, any response? How can I use the 3rd method to connect to another cluster in same Ruby process?